# Javascript adding object in array from dynamic input form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading input form and getting ids as `tle_breakup_0`, `rtl_breakup_0`, `tle_breakup_1`, `rtl_breakup_1`,  `tle_breakup_2`, `rtl_breakup_2`.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
  var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
  $inputs.each(function () {
    var attr_name = this.id;
    var attr_value = $(this).val();

  });

});
```

How can i get the Below is the expected output where i want to collect breakups index id wise .

```
{
  "breakup": [{

    "tle_breakup_0": "12",
    "rtl_breakup_0": "12"
  },

  {
    "tle_breakup_1": "12",
    "rtl_breakup_1": "12"
  },
  {
    "tle_breakup_2": "12",
    "rtl_breakup_2": ""
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You said what you are doing but not what is the problem that you have.

Comment: Above is the expected output where i want to collect breakups index id wise is my requirement .

Comment: Looks like you need to group by the digit at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a 'group by' on the last digit of each `id`. Since you're using jquery you can just use the `each` to group into an object declared outside of it. Here extracting the last digit using [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and then initiliazing objects that don't already exist using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and setting the property using bracket notation. Finally the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the grouped obect are assigned to the `result.breakup`.

```js
const result = { breakup: [] };

$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 
  const grouped ={}
  $('#myForm input').each(function () {
    const attr_name = this.id;
    const attr_value = $(this).val();

    const key = attr_name.match(/\d+$/)?.[0];
    if (key!==undefined){
      (grouped[key] ??= {})[attr_name] = attr_value;
    }
  });
  
  result.breakup=Object.values(grouped);
  
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
    <input id="tle_breakup_0" type="text" value="10"/>
    <input id="rtl_breakup_0" type="text" value="10"/>
    <input id="tle_breakup_1" type="text" value="11"/>
    <input id="rtl_breakup_1" type="text" value="11"/>
    <input id="tle_breakup_2" type="text" value="12"/>
    <input id="rtl_breakup_2" type="text" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or, if you were looking for more dynamic assignment based on other parts of the `id` you can simply parse these out and use them as needed.

```js
const result = {};

$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const grouped = {}
  $('#myForm input').each(function () {
    const attr_name = this.id;
    const attr_value = $(this).val();

    const [, group, key] = attr_name.split('_');
    if (group !== undefined && key !== undefined) {
      grouped[group] ??= {};
      grouped[group][key] ??= {};
      grouped[group][key][attr_name] = attr_value;
    }
  });

  const groupedResult = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(grouped).map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.values(v)]));

  Object.assign(result, groupedResult);

  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
    <input id="tle_breakup_0" type="text" value="10"/>
    <input id="rtl_breakup_0" type="text" value="10"/>
    <input id="tle_breakup_1" type="text" value="11"/>
    <input id="rtl_breakup_1" type="text" value="11"/>
    <input id="tle_other_2" type="text" value="12"/>
    <input id="rtl_other_2" type="text" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```